# image from top() and box with text below the image

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to do something like the image attached

[image]

Here is what I've tried:

```
Container(
    height: 300.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(image_url),
        )
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: AutoSizeText(
                my_text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                maxLines: 1,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center
            )
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: Offset(1, 1),
            ),
          ],
        )
    )
)
```

The problems of this code are:

- If the image is not high enough, a white bar appears on top of the screen between the app bar and image
- The position of the box with the text depends on the height of the container: I need the box is always half inside and half outside the image

Comment: This can be achieved by using the Stack widget. Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a stack widget for it, but make sure you use BoxFit and as Cover which will fill the entire height of your container.

```
Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 300.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.jpg'),
            )),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 280),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("jitesh",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center)),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                  spreadRadius: 1,
                  blurRadius: 3,
                  offset: Offset(1, 1),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```